# Why grep doesn't match the rest of the line before the space?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

arrvar=( $(cat input.txt | grep -Poh '^[A-Z0-9_]+=.+') )
arrlen=${#arrvar[@]}
let arrlen--

i=0
while : ; do
    echo "item $i..: ${arrvar[i]}"

    let i++
    if [ $i -gt $arrlen ]; then
      break
    fi
done
```

Whit this content in input.txt:

```
HELLO=123 456
STACK=456 756
OVERFLOW=756 789
```

The result is the following:

```
item 0..: HELLO=123
item 1..: 456
item 2..: STACK=456
item 3..: 756
item 4..: OVERFLOW=756
item 5..: 789
```

Why it doesn't matches nothing before the space if the expression `.+` match all the characters?

I'm looking for this output:

```
item 0..: HELLO=123 456
item 1..: STACK=456 756
item 2..: OVERFLOW=756 789
```

Could you give me a delailed explanation, please? I'm quite interested.

Comment: can't solve the puzzle offhand, but try `^[A-Z0-9_]+=(.|[ ])+` as a regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `IFS` to newline by doing `IFS=$'\n'`. This will separate the fields on newlines instead of `space` which is the default value of `IFS`.

So re-using your existing script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
arrvar=( $(cat input.txt | grep -Poh '^[A-Z0-9_]+=.+') )
arrlen=${#arrvar[@]}
let arrlen--

i=0
while : ; do
    echo "item $i..: ${arrvar[i]}"

    let i++
    if [ $i -gt $arrlen ]; then
      break
    fi
done
```

Comment: But now I cant split the items like this: `split=${arrvar[i]//=/ }` Any idea to do this? Thanks

Comment: @JohnDoe You can always `unset` the `IFS` or while assigning the new value to `IFS` backup the old one. [Here](http://unixtesting.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/ifs-variable-tips-and-tricks/) some tips and tricks.